# Converting to Prenex Normal Form.

Tags: predicate-logic

I need convert $ \forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \sim Q(x,y))  \vee   \exists  x  \exists  y(P(x,y) \sim Q(y))$ into Prenex Normal Form.

Can I use this formula: $(\exists x\phi )\lor \psi $  is equivalent to $\exists x(\phi \lor \psi )$ like
$$ \forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \sim Q(x,y))  \vee   \exists  x  \exists  y(P(x,y) \sim Q(y)) $$ is equivalent to
$$ \exists  x \forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \sim Q(x,y))  \vee    \exists  y(P(x,y) \sim Q(y))$$ is equivalent to
$$ \exists  y \exists  x \forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \sim Q(x,y))  \vee    (P(x,y) \sim Q(y))$$
Is it converting to Prenex Normal Form?

Comment: First you have to rename $x$ and $y$ with e.g. $w$ and $z$ in one of thetwo disjuncts.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA is it right $ \exists z \exists w \forall x \forall y(P(x,y) \sim Q(x,y))  \vee  (P(w,z) \sim Q(z))$